# couldn't find schema information in mono android style

Tags: android, xml, mono, schema

I'm building a simple mono android app. I've designed a simple style to set the background of a textview:

The xml file in my Resouces/Drawable Folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#DD2ECCFA" />
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp"/>/>
</shape>
```

I get the following message in vs 2012:

> couldn't find schema information for the element 'shape'.

And a couple more messages for corners, stroke, solid...

This message causes problem when I install the app on a real device but on the emulator every thing is fine.

I'm using java jdk version 6. Thanks. Any help will do.